# What makes Google Maps/Youtube able to display the 'Complete this action with' menu?

Tags: android

And if possible, how can I get this behavior for 'my' app?

For example, when a user navigates to the URL 'example.com/*' (any page starting with example.com), I'd want it so the 'complete this action with' menu shows up listing all of the browsers and this particular app?

I've done some reading of the Intent documentation, but it seems like you can only create them for phone data, not web URLs.

Edit: anyone? I've looked into this some more, but haven't had any luck. I'd like to set a bounty, but I don't have that option yet. If it isn't possible, I guess I'll just make a way to paste in a URL.

Comment: Do you want your app to show up in this list in other applications or do you want to open a list with all of the available apps from your application?

Comment: I want my app to show up in the list. I'm hoping that browsers see if they can trigger this list on every page load, but starting to think that's not likely.

Comment: Andrew Koester gave a really good answer so you should probably reward some of that reputation seeing as it will all be lost tomorrow if you don't give it to someone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's pretty simple, actually! What you want is an intent filter with the BROWSABLE category set, and a `<data>` tag set up to match your URL.

Inside your `<activity>`, add:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

and set up the action and categories how you want, and change the data tag values to something relevant to your application. This will allow your link (in this case, `http://www.example.com/`) to be launched in your application by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ires
It's really well described how to use intent filters and why, especially in the section Common cases (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ccases).